# GUI App shows File not found in directory Error

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, python-idle

I made a GUI for a python program that allows me to read a csv file and display the data on the GUI. The GUI works perfectly fine when I run the program through IDLE. However when I try to run the program file as it is from Windows Explorer it shows the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\gui1.py", line 43, in find_result
    with open("RESULTS.csv") as a:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'RESULTS.csv'
```

This is the program code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import csv


root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Results')

tk.Label(root,text="Enter your Roll Number:").grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root,text="Name:").grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root,text="Total (Core 5 Subjects):").grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root,text="Total (Best 5 Subjects):").grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root,text="Percentage:").grid(row=7,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root,text="Rank:").grid(row=8
                                 ,column=1,sticky=tk.W)

rno=tk.StringVar()


name_=tk.StringVar()
t1_=tk.StringVar()
t2_=tk.StringVar()
perc_=tk.StringVar()
rank_=tk.StringVar()
                   
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=rno,justify=tk.RIGHT).grid(row=1,column=2,padx=3,pady=3)
def find_result():
    

    tk.Label(root,textvariable=name_,justify=tk.RIGHT).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=tk.E)

    tk.Label(root,textvariable=t1_,justify=tk.RIGHT).grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=tk.E)

    tk.Label(root,textvariable=t2_,justify=tk.RIGHT).grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=tk.E)

    tk.Label(root,textvariable=perc_,justify=tk.RIGHT).grid(row=7,column=2,sticky=tk.E)

    tk.Label(root,textvariable=rank_,justify=tk.RIGHT).grid(row=8,column=2,sticky=tk.E)

    with open("RESULTS.csv") as a:
        reader=csv.reader(a)
        for i in reader:
            if i!=[]:
                if i[0]==rno.get():
                    name=i[1][2:]
                    t1=i[19]
                    t2=i[20]
                    perc=i[21]
                    rank=i[22]

                    name_.set(name)
                    t1_.set(t1)
                    t2_.set(t2)
                    perc_.set(perc)
                    rank_.set(rank)


tk.Button(root, text="Check your Result",command=find_result).grid(row=2,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Opening program with IDLE:

[image: Opening program with IDLE]

Opening program through Explorer:

[image: Opening program through Explorer]

Answer (score 0):

`open("RESULTS.csv")` looks for that file in the current working directory, whatever that happens to be.  This must be different for the two different ways you run the code.  Do one of the following.

1. Give `open` an absolute path to the file instead of a relative one.  If you know the location of the data file relative to the location of the program file, use `__file__`, which has the location of the program file, as the starting point.  Note 1: that when working interactively, without running a file, `__file__` does not exist. Note 2: If you do not understand 'absolute path', do a web search.
2. Explicitly set the current directory to the one containing the file with `os.chdir(path)`. where path is absolute, not relative.  This is more useful if opening several files in that directory.